# How to sort the product collection on an attribute?

Tags: configurable-product, sorting, product-collection

I am doing the following to sort the product collection based on an attribute whose values are actually of type "String" but can only hold `0` or `1`. I also mentioned *default value* as `0`.

```
$collection = $this->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort('attr_name' *1, 'DESC');
```

In the above code, since the attribute type is "string", I added `*1` to convert the *string* type to *Integer* as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12527824/1577396).

What should I do to sort the product collection based on a attribute which is of type string but has only values `0` and `1`?

PS: The collection is being sorted with other attribute in `__construct` function already and then made to `setCollection($collection)`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the fact that it's a string as value in the database shouldn't matter. MySQL will ignore the type.

So you can just add the `attr_name` and the direction of the sorting.

```
$this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('attr_name', 'DESC');
```

When using flat product data tables please make sure the attribute is added to the table. This can be done on the attribute edit page by turning `Used in Product Listing` on.

To debug it might help to output or log the query and optionally execute it in, for example, PHPMyAdmin to see what happens and tweak it quickly to get the desired results

```
Mage::log((string)$this->getCollection()->getSelect());
```

Comment: I did the same.. the attribute values for each collection are coming like `0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0...` when I used `DESC` instead of `1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...`.

Comment: Thanks but it is not flat product data tables..

Comment: updated my answer :)

Comment: I did the Mage::log as you explained. I got a big sql query. Nothing is happening based on my attribute in that sql query.

Comment: Sorry, there is also my attribute name in that sql query but I can't see collection in frontend. The count is also visible as `1` instead of `21`.